# How can I render 3D objects and particle systems in front of a Screen Space - Overlay Camera?

Tags: unity, rendering, camera, particles, draw-order

I am using Unity 2019 with the Universal Render Pipeline.  I have a canvas that is using Screen Space - Overlay render mode.  I cannot change my render mode to Screen Space - Camera, because it is not currently supported by the Universal Render Pipeline.

How can I have a particle system, or any other 3D objects, render on top of my canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To render 3D objects on top of your canvas:**

1. Create a new Canvas in Screen Space - Overlay.
2. Add a RawImage to that canvas.
3. Create a new Render Texture.
4. Add the Render Texture to the Raw Image.
5. Create a new Camera.
6. Set the camera to Solid Color background with an alpha of 0.
7. Set the output texture of the camera to be the Render Texture you created.

**You can now render 3D objects on top of your canvas; however, there are extra steps for particle systems:**

8. Create a material.  Set its shader to Universal Render Pipeline/2D/Sprite-Lit-Default.
9. Add your particle sprite to the Diffuse of your material.
10. In the Renderer settings of your particle system, replace the material with the one you just created.

**You should be good to go!**

(If you have any problems, try going to your Render Settings and change the Anti Aliasing to 8x.)

WARNING: This will eat your battery. Be sure to disable the camera when not in use.